# Test if a method exists in entity from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to edit the default form template to include a thumbnail preview of an image when I display an upload field, so I put a method called getFormThumbnail() in my entity that returns the path. When the entity has the method it works, but when it doens't I get an error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserTranslation' does not have a method 'getFormThumbnail' in C:\...\symfony\vendor\knplabs\doctrine-behaviors\src\Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslatableMethods.php line 140") in kernel.root_dir/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig at line 43.

500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
```

I am editing the code in `{% block form_widget_simple %}`

I added :

```
{% if type == 'file' %}
    {% if form.vars.form.parent.vars.value.getFormThumbnail is not null %}
        <img src="{{ form.vars.form.parent.vars.value.getFormThumbnail | imagine_filter('thumb_250') }}" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px">
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This code works perfectly when getFormThumbnail exists. So I tried adding `is defined` and it doesn't work, I even tried things like:

```
form is defined
and
form is not null
and
form.vars is defined
and
form.vars is not null
and
form.vars.form is defined
and
form.vars.form is not null
and
form.vars.form.parent is defined
and
form.vars.form.parent is not null
and
form.vars.form.parent.vars is defined
and
form.vars.form.parent.vars is not null
and
form.vars.form.parent.vars.value is defined
and
form.vars.form.parent.vars.value is not null
and
form.vars.form.parent.vars.value.getFormThumbnail is defined
and
form.vars.form.parent.vars.value.getFormThumbnail is not null
```

Still, I always get the same error, the line in the error by the way is the line where I test if getFormThumbnail is defined

So if the error is `does not have a method` is there a way to test if it has a method?

Comment: Have you tried `{% form.vars.form.parent.vars.value.getFormThumbnail() is defined %}`?

Comment: Hi @Oylex i test that `is defined` works well with object but  i don't test it on  a form object field. Hope this help. Let me know if you find a solution!

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk I tested and it doesn't work, however I used the solution provided in the answer I accepted which works.

Comment: It's weird. Maybe it's because of form object as @Matteo supposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom fragment only for that field. So you don't have to check if the method exists or not http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field.

Or you can create a form type extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Comment: I created a form type extension called `thumb_image` (instead of just `file`) which expects the method to exists and it works perfectly.